# Editor place holder in source file

Tags: swift2

I don't understand the problem here, my code has no bugs, but when I hit run nothing appears on the emulator. I need help, how can I see my images appear as a `Scrollview` on the emulator ?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!
    var imageArray = [UIImage]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        mainScrollView.frame = view.frame
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_1750"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_1754")]
        for i in 0..<imageArray.count{
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.image = imageArray[i]
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)
            mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat( i + 1)
            mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        }


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: imageArray.append(UIImage(named: "10.jpg")!)

Comment: can u like be more specific please, appreciate ur response selvadurai

Comment: and for the record I would love to add a search bar to this, how is it done, i have to submit this homework on monday I wish someone to help me out here am stuck

Comment: imageArray to add number of images as you required and use UITableview not scrollview. Tableview have scroll function so no need to worry.  Then create sear bar and use predicate that will help you !

Comment: if my answer helpful, just up vote it please.